# express.js - How to correctly change language with i18next when using express-session?

Tags: express-session, i18next

I preferred not to have language related parameters in the url, so I decided to change the current language using express-session.

After standard configuration of express-session for a proof of concept by reading the documentation (with perhaps misunderstanding) I had an endpoint like:

```
app.get('myRoute', function(req, res) {
  req.i18n.changeLanguage('en'); // will not load that!!! assert it was preloaded
});
```

which as you read by the comment (from documentation) "will not load"

Then I came up with this code that worked for me:

```
router.get('/chz', function(req, res){
 if(req.session){
  req.session.lng = 'zh-TW';
 }
 res.redirect('back');
});
```

Is there any potential problem with this code (soft of optimization, or security, etc.) and I must somehow use i18n.changeLanguage() to change the language when using express-session? If not, then what is the usage of i18n.changeLanguage()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the language detector coming with the i18next-express-middleware: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware#detector-options

it already grabs the lng from `req.session.lng` on every request if enabling that in the order option:

```
{
  // order and from where user language should be detected
  order: [/*'path'*/, 'session',  'querystring', 'cookie', 'header'],
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what is doing the job above! If client request a language change, a handler in server side must reflect that into req.session.lng, only after that it will be detected by the detector right? This is my handler above, but I'm not sure if it has no performance/security impact, because I didn't find any similar, so I'm asking to make sure. If a handler is not needed, please tell me how the implementation must be.